# SQLite getting data

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a spinner widget and I want to populate some data when user clicks on one of the items from spinner. So I have the position number like 0,1,2,3... for spinner items.

Now I have a table which have three fields as

```
  _id    cid    relatedname

   1       1          A
   2       1          B
   3       2          C
   4       2          D
   5       2          E
```

I want when a user clicks position 1 from spinner then it will check for cid and all the relatedname will be displayed whose cid is 1.

How to do this ?

Comment: what is your problem? querying the table or knowing when the selected element has changed?

Comment: how can i relate position and cid .how to iterate through cid and get realtedname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setOnItemChangelistener()` to spinner then do as follows in tat listener.

```
loadRelatedName(position + 1);    

void loadRelatedName(int cid) 
{
     sql = " SELECT * FROM table WHERE cid = " + cid;
     Cursor c = db.select(sql);
     if (c ! null)
        while(c.moveToNext()) {
            Syso("Related Name : " + c.getString[2]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `OnItemSelectedListener` to the spinner to get the selected item.

[See this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html)

There you can get the position. With that you can query your database. Probably something like:

```
SELECT relatedname from mytable where cid=<selectedpos>
```

This will get you all entries where `cid` has the same value as the selected position.
Note: It may be that the indexes of the spinner are zero based and `cid` is not. So maybe you need to add `1` to the selected position before querying the table